# How Can I sent Email from magento Observer to MailHog?

Tags: magento2, email

I caught data $email and $comment that I must send

```
<?php

namespace Dev\ProductComments\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;


class EmailObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Observer initialization code...
        // You can use dependency injection to get any class this observer may need.
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $email = $observer->getData('sentEmail');
        $comment = $observer->getData('sentComment');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailhog works like an smtp server

So you host mailhog somewhere. The mailhog interface gives you the mail details you need. When working locally I use docker.

Then use an extension in magento which allows you to configure smtp and all your magento mail goes to mailhog

You cant just do it for one process via magento. You could code using pure php and a third party library and hard code mailhog credentials.

Comment: understand , Thank you !